# serial_diff with bucket_sort doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch

We are trying to get serial_diff on the previous hour and sort the top diffs. The following doesnt work. It works if we cut out the bucket_sort.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "campaigns": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "campaign_id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "my_date_histo": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "sample_time",
                        "interval": "hour"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "the_sum": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "delta_clicks"
                            }
                        },
                        "last_hour_diff": {
                            "serial_diff": {
                                "buckets_path": "the_sum",
                                "lag": 1
                            }
                        },
                        "last_hour_diff_sort": {
                            "bucket_sort": {
                                "sort": [
                                    {
                                        "last_hour_diff": {
                                            "order": "desc"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
```

The error we are getting with the bucket_sort is:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "root_cause": [],
>           "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
>           "reason": "",
>           "phase": "fetch",
>           "grouped": true,
>           "failed_shards": [],
>           "caused_by": {
>               "type": "null_pointer_exception",
>               "reason": null
>           }
>       },
>       "status": 500 }

Comment: You cannot run a pipeline aggregation over another pipeline aggregation. You can sort the buckets by `the_sum` (a metric agg) but not by `last_hour_diff` (a pipeline agg)

Comment: @Val - any other workaround you know of?